# HP ProCurve 2920, MAC filter

Tags: hp, switch, mac, filter

I have few HP 2920. They are connected to another HP modular switch via uplinks. When I check which devices are connected via MAC I can only see MAC addresses on uplink ports (idk why I can't see particular MAC on particular port on 2920. They are showed also in uplink ports).

What I want to do, is to prevent another users which are not allowed to, to plug into those 2920 switches. How can I block and allow only recognized (for example those, which are connected in this moment) devices connect with Network?
I have not big experience with HP Switches so..

My Network looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P44v.jpg

and what I want to achieve: (red PC won't have connection)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UzEK.jpg

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port-security settings will accomplish this for you. I'd set it up to learn the MACs of your authorized devices and proceed from there. 
Instructions:

http://whp-aus1.cold.extweb.hp.com/pub/networking/software/Security-Oct2005-59906024-Chap09-Port_Security.pdf

Comment: If I can ask, I did this as you said, but I have one small question. If I use port disabling while connecting with different MAC, how long the port will be disabled? If I will reconnect properly MAC, port will be still disabled for some amount of time, right? But how long? 5min, 15? Day? Or I have to manually clear it?

Comment: The default value for the length of time a MAC address stays in the table is 300 seconds. However, when a new device is plugged in and negotiates with the switch, the new MAC address is populated immediately if negotiation is successful.

Comment: You're most welcome.